# Custom Annotation Processor with Netbeans Module

Tags: java, netbeans, annotations

I'm doing work with a (non Maven, I believe) Netbeans module, which is being used as a Plugin for a program built on top of the Netbeans platform.

What I wanted to do was use custom annotations to add a sort of documentation of how to use the GUI elements (of the plugin I'm working on), when a user goes to the help menu and selects "how to use".

My thought was create a custom annotation, where a user supplies name, and help information for a class.  Then the annotation processor goes through the annotations, and outputs a class with the annotation information stored in a class field.  This class can then be extended from, and used to display the information in a useful way.

**Following this example** https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/annotations-custom.html

I'm using Java 7, but both the Module and the Annotation Processor Jar are compiled as Java 6.  My Netbeans Version is 7.3.1, however I believe the module is being developed for Netbeans Platform 7.0.1.

I have the annotation, and annotation processor compiled into a Jar, which if I use with a regular java project, it works as expected.

However, I cannot get the processor to run during compiling with the Netbeans module project.

I tried adding the Annotation Processor class to the META-INF.services, javax.annotation.processing.Processor file, in the netbeans module.

I tried adding the Annotation Processor class to the META-INF.services, javax.annotation.processing.Processor file, in the Annotation Processor project. (This made it work with my test Project)

I tried adding the -processor compiler flag to the netbeans module project to use the specific annotation processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the extends relationship between my class and the expected auto generated class, output from the annotation processor, the code compiled.  But at that point I noticed that the annotation processor was in fact being run.

I added the extends relationship back in, and cleaned and compiled again, and it failed to compile but the annotation processor was run, and successfully generated the output file as hoped.  I hit build, without cleaning, and it built a final time, and worked as expected.

I don't know what is causing this, it appears to be, at least for a Netbeans module project, that the build order is different than a regular Java Project.  Or perhaps there are several intermediate build steps which don't always get cleaned up.